# How to handle the click function in Access form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I create a form in access 2010 like this:

[image]

When I click to the OnClick event, it open this window:

[image]

I don't know how to convert this marco to VBA.

I already check to `Allway use event proceduces`

Don't tell me follow this step:

1. List item Open the form or report in Design view.
2. On the Tools menu, point to
   Macro, and then click Convert Form's Macros To Visual Basic or
   Convert Report's Macros To Visual Basic.

because I cannot find where the `Convert` button, If you can find it, please show me the picture.

My tool options missing that button, I don't know why?

[image]

Please help me the simple way to handle button click by VBA in access 2010. It's must be a simple function but it is not.

**Update 1:**
The full tools should be like below, I don't know why my access missing it.
[image]

Comment: That menu option not enabled automatically.  Take a look at this link... http://superuser.com/questions/533518/in-excel-2013-where-are-visual-basic-vba-macros-addin-tools

Comment: Hi Wayne, this topic talk about enable Developer tab in Ribbon of excel, this tab doesnot exist in access.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Press the button in the top left corner and go to 'access options'.

Then go to 'Customize', choose commands from all commands and add the applicable button to your quick access toolbar, which is usually in your top left corner as well. This at least enables the button for you, though not in the 'correct' spot.

[image]

[image]